# Error in xcode when i try to compile using a MPVolumeView

Tags: objective-c, media-player, linker-errors, mpvolumeview

xcode gives me that error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPVolumeView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in VolumeViewController.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

this is viewDidload of viewcontroller.

```
- (void)viewDidload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)] autorelease];
    volumeView.center = CGPointMake(160,134);
    [volumeView sizeToFit];
    volumeView.showsVolumeSlider=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:volumeView];
}
```

I import:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MPVolumeView.h>
```

What could be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that the linker cannot find the class MPVolumeView

You need to add the library or framework that includes this class to XCode

Comment: :) Very simple! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Add MediaPlayer framework in your project:

Project **->** Build phases **->** Link binary with libraries:

[image]